# StatFs on Android 8+

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm getting `Caused by android.system.ErrnoException statvfs failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` error when using StatFs, the phone crashing are mostly on API 26 to 30.
It's not related to Scoped storage as API 26 doesn't have it.

```kotlin
val externalFilesDirs = applicationContext.getExternalFilesDirs(null)
var localAvailableBytesLeft: Long? = null
var extAvailableBytesLeft: Long? = null
if(externalFilesDirs.first() != null && EnvironmentCompat.getStorageState(externalFilesDirs.first()) == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    val localDownloadDirectory = File(externalFilesDirs.first(), "downloads").absolutePath
    localAvailableBytesLeft = StatFs(localDownloadDirectory).availableBytes // Crash here
}
if(externalFilesDirs.getOrNull(1) != null && EnvironmentCompat.getStorageState(externalFilesDirs[1]) == Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
    val externalDownloadDirectory = File(externalFilesDirs[1], "downloads").absolutePath
    extAvailableBytesLeft = StatFs(externalDownloadDirectory).availableBytes
}
```

`localDownloadDirectory` is a path like `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.my.package/files/downloads`

I haven't asked for runtime permission as it is the package of my application and it doesn't require permission. However my AndroidManifest has `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

I also have

**provider_paths.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
    <files-path name="files" path="."/>
    <external-files-path name="external_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Comment: There is getFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDir() and getExternalFilesDirs(). And you ate calling those external files dir(s) 'filesDir'. Very fine! How confusing!

Comment: StatFs(getExternalFilesDirs()[0].getAbsolutePath());

Comment: StatFs(getExternalFilesDirs()[1].getAbsolutePath());

Comment: Well yeah that's what I'm calling and it gets me an error, i'll change the naming for better readability :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out all I needed to add was `localDownloadDirectory.mkdirs()` and `externalDownloadDirectory.mkdirs()`